# How to define Bounds of a 3D grid (x,y,z - range) in a netCDF file

Tags: vtk, netcdf, paraview

I am trying to create a netCDF file based on a VTK file with .vti extension.The metadata or the header information for the VTK file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <VTKFile type="ImageData" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
  <ImageData WholeExtent="0 256 0 192 0 128" Origin="0 0 0" Spacing=" 4.000000 4.000000 1.000000  ">
   <Piece Extent="0 256 0 192 0 128">
    <PointData Scalars="Distance Field">
     <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Distance Field" format="ascii">
```

And the header for the netCDF file looks like this:

```
netcdf DistField {
dimensions:
    z = 129 ;
    y = 193 ;
    x = 257 ;
variables:
    float Distance\ Field(z, y, x) ;
data:
```

When I open the two files in paraview I see the following information:

VTK File info in paraview

[image: vtk file]

NetCDF File info in paraview

[image: netCDF file]

I don't know how to define the bounds value in netCDF so paraview displays the same information. Any help on this would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Can you set the spacing in netcdf?

Comment: @lib I am very new to netcdf and I don't have a clue. However I have seen variables in netcdf file with bounds attribute.

Comment: @anup if it's just an attribute that you want to set, look at the Unidata [attributes](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf/Attributes.html) page.

Comment: @TimothyBrown that is what I thought I had to do, but it turns out I had to define the dimensions as variables and put the range of values as data for the dimension variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out: I had to define the dimensions as variables and put the range of values as data for the dimension variables.

Comment: which utilities did you use to define and populate the data?